# Storing information in an array from foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

If I have a loop like this, and an array which stores information:

```
$itemArray = array();
foreach ($a->getDetails() as $b) 
{
    if ($b->getValue1() !== $b->getValue2()) 
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($b->getId(), $itemArray))
        {
            $itemArray[$b->getId()] = array('name' => $b->getName(), 'age' => $b->getAge());
        }

    $personName = $itemArray[$b->getId()]['name'];
    $personAge  = $itemArray[$b->getId()]['age'];

    $content    = ('Name is: ' . $personName . ', age is: ' . $personAge);
    }
}
```

Right now this only outputs a single 'person' for a single value of $b which is mismatched, how would I go about storing multiple values of $b being mismatched?

I basically want the output to be something along the lines of:

Name is: Dave, age is 30.

Name is: John, age is 40.

But right now only one 'person' would get output even if there were two instances where

```
$b->getValue1() !== $b->getValue2()
```

A sample output of $a->getDetails():

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
  object(PersonDetail)#322 (41) {
["collItemTemplateFieldPersonValues":protected]=>
NULL
["id":protected]=>
int(2375434)
["person_id":protected]=>
int(2184229)
["person_details_id":protected]=>
int(4563874)
["person_details_type_id":protected]=>
NULL
["name":protected]=>
string(4) "Test"
["person_namecode":protected]=>
string(9) "PERSON_ID"
["person_age":protected]=>
int(30)
```

Comment: can you paste the "$a->getDetails()" input

Comment: can you post all the objects as well?

Comment: I posted a small sample of $a->getDetails()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already stored all you need in array, you've just to loop through :)

```
$itemArray = array();
foreach ($a->getDetails() as $b) {
    if ($b->getValue1() !== $b->getValue2()) {
        if (!array_key_exists($b->getId(), $itemArray)) {
            $itemArray[$b->getId()] = array('name' => $b->getName(), 'age' => $b->getAge());
        }
    }
}
if (count($itemArray) > 0) {
    foreach($itemArray as $item) {
        $personName = $item['name'];
        $personAge  = $item['age'] ;
        $content    = ('Name is: ' . $personName . ', age is: ' . $personAge);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense thanks!  If I wanted to say.. send an email within php using the output from the array, all in a SINGLE email, how would I create a variable to hold all the data?

Comment: @Sudoscience You have to ask a new question for this, we must keep SO clean :), also if you accept this answer, you must check it and optionally upvote it...  share me your question's link and i will help you

Comment: Done! Here is the new question Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650419/grab-data-from-array-and-combine-to-send-email-using-php